# D8 - Can 2 Entities share the same name?

Tags: 8

I have written a module that has an entity type of name "redirect.php".
So the object is actually called redirect.

As far as I know there is a module called like that. There are also entities with this exact name. The DB base field has a longer name that will not create issues.

Is Drupal smart enough to look at the namespace or will two classes / objects with the same name create issues?

Thanks

Comment: The class names should be irrelevant, they're in separate namespaces so if there was a clash it would be at the language level. I'd imagine you just need to make sure the entity type ID, set in the annotation of your entity class, is unique

Comment: Thanks. I will try out what you just suggested / by installing the other module.